# How to execute server and client tests in one command/process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, angularjs, mocha.js

as I'm developing a web application using AngularJS in the front-end and Node.js in the server. For now I'm writing tests for the node server (based on Express) using Mocha (+ Chai + Supertest), and client side tests using Mocha and Testacular as a test runner, since Testacular is the tool of choice with Angular.

Note that the Angular app is "embedded" in the node app, as it's located in the template files.

My testing process : for server tests, I just `npm test`, i.e. `mocha <my-test-folder> <my-test-options>` ; for client tests, I launch a Testacular server that watches changes in the desired files. But I don't like this parallel and disconnected process and I'm sure there's a better, unified automated way.

Could help me refine the process ?

Answer (score 0):

In my travels I haven't seen a precident for this, but you should be able to achieve it using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).  You can make a grunt target that calls both.

I have a [github project](https://github.com/roytruelove/angular-seed-grunt) that should help show how to use testacular on an angular project using grunt which will at least help with the client part; will help get you part of the way there.